# Sending a Float32Array via socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am currently stuck at sending a Float32Array via socket.io to another socket.

There is no real code to show, since I am only using `socket.emit` and `socket.on`.

On the other end of the socket the Float32Array remains as a Object.
Here are to pictures from the Float32Array before emiting and the remains after emiting.

Before: [image: Before]

Remains: [image: Remains]

If it is not possible to send the Float32Array to another socket, would it be possible to send a Blob to another socket?

Both sockets are Chrome clients. `socket.emit` emits to the server and the server emits to every client.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary)?

Comment: Yes, but I think I am getting it wrong or don't understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending in the client:

```
var array = new Float32Array(...);
socket.emit('data', array.buffer);
```

Receiving in the client:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  var array = new Float32Array(data);
  ...
});
```

I don't think you need to do anything special in the server, just pass along the data that you receive from the first client to the second client.

Comment: I do already have a Float32Array on the sending client but the array doesn't have a buffer property.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to refer to the index 0. Thanks a lot, it's working now.