# Sending and casting a Float32Array after JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, stream, audio-streaming

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815262/sending-a-float32array-via-socket-io) - I'm trying to send a `Float32Array` from one client to another, but I need to use `JSON.stringify` before sending the message.

On the sending side I use:

```
audioBuffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
var aud = { "sessionId": sessionId, "streamData": audioBuffer, "client": "student", "type": "audio" }
ws.send(JSON.stringify(aud));
```

On the receiving sise I use:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(message.data);
var streamData = msg.streamData;
var kbuff = new Float32Array(streamData);
context.decodeAudioData(kbuff, onBuffer, onDecodeBufferError);
```

But this results in the receiving side getting an `Object` that I cannot seem to cast to a `Float32Array`:

When the sending side sends the data:

[image]

When the receiving side gets the data:

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON](https://json.org/) doesn't understand `Float32Array`. If you stringify a `Float32Array` (for instance, `JSON.stringify(Float32Array.of(20, 250, 444))`), you get something that looks like this:

```
{"0":20,"1":250,"2":444}
```

You have two options:

1. Convert the array to a standard array of numbers before `stringify` and then convert it back after `JSON.parse`, or
2. Send it as-is and convert the resulting object back to a `Float32Array` after `JSON.parse`.

Since converting a `Float32Array` to an array of numbers won't be lossy, and maintains the semantics well, that's what I'd do:

```js
const original = Float32Array.of(20, 250, 444);
const json = JSON.stringify(Array.from(original));
console.log(json);
const received = new Float32Array(JSON.parse(json));
console.log(received);
```

If this array is part of a greater structure, you may need a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax) with `JSON.stringify` and [`reviver` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Syntax) for `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I added the `JSON.parse` function on `streamData` I get an error "Unexpected token o in JSON"

Comment: @KobyDouek - Look again at the answer. :-) You have to do things at **both** ends (for #1), not just one end. (Also: What is producing the JSON? It shouldn't be producing invalid JSON, no matter what you feed it. It should, at worst, leave things out that it doesn't understand, or raise an error.)

Comment: I did, I changed it to : `"streamData": Array.from(audioBuffer)`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @KobyDouek - Yes. That will serialize correctly, and you can then use `new Float32Array(result.streamData)` to get a `Float32Array` at the other end. See the live example.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.. still it throws an error in the `JSON.parse` attempt. I will check if my issue is somewhere else. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KobyDouek - That means something is producing invalid JSON, but it isn't the `Array.from(...)` part. Good luck finding it!

Comment: Got it - added `JSON.stringify` on the Array it self before stringifying the message. Thanks boss.